# suspend IO function never return

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, blocking, coroutinescope

I have difficulties writing an UDP message receive loop for Android.

In the following code, in `receiveLoop`, the call to `receiveMessages` never returns and I therefore never enter the message treatment loop.
Note that I am still able to receive packets, but it stops when the channel buffer is full.

I would expect `receiveMessages` to return immediately, while the blocking IO loop inside it would still run forever.

```
class MySocketUDP(private val params: SocketParams) {


    private val rcvSocket: DatagramSocket by lazy {
        val sock = DatagramSocket(params.rcvPort)
        sock.reuseAddress = true
        sock.soTimeout = 1000
        sock
    }

    suspend fun receiveMessages(channel: SendChannel<Message>) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val buf = ByteArray(MAX_MSG_SIZE)
            while (true) {
                val pkt = DatagramPacket(buf, buf.size)
                try {
                    if (channel.isClosedForSend) {
                        break
                    }
                    rcvSocket.receive(pkt)
                    val msg = packetToMessage(buf, 0, pkt.length)
                    Log.d("SOCKET", "filling channel with $msg")
                    channel.send(msg)
                } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
                } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyModel {

    private suspend fun receiveLoop(socket: MySocketUDP) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val channel = Channel<Message>(16)
            socket.receiveMessages(channel)
            Log.d("MODEL", "Entering msg loop")
            for (msg in channel) {
                dispatchRcvMessage(msg)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

1. Why does `receiveMessages` never return while it is running in the `IO` dispatcher and called from the `Main` dispatcher?
2. Do I need to actually spawn a thread to such producer/consumer work?
3. Can you show how to achieve such long blocking code nicely in a "coroutine-friendly" manner?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you expect `receiveMessages` to return without waiting for the loop to finish? Suspend functions are synchronous, so they're like any other function and they return only when they finish to execute their body. Ad. 2: Yes and no. You need to spawn a new coroutine, not thread.

Comment: @broot I misunderstood the role of `withContext`. I thought it would necessarily create an asynchronous call if new context is different than the calling context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `receiveMessages()` is a suspend function which calls another suspend function `withContext()`, which in turn has an infinite loop. So calling `socket.receiveMessages(channel)` will suspend code execution while the loop is not finished.
2. You need to launch separate coroutines for consumer and producer, e.g. using [`launch`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html) function.
3. Some example of using coroutines:

   ```
    val someScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    private suspend fun receiveLoop(socket: MySocketUDP) = someScope.launch {
        val channel = Channel<Message>(16)
        socket.receiveMessages(channel)
        Log.d("MODEL", "Entering msg loop")
        for (msg in channel) {
            dispatchRcvMessage(msg)
        }
    }

    // In MySocketUDP
    suspend fun receiveMessages(channel: SendChannel<Message>) {
        someAnotherScope.launch { // or can use coroutineScope builder function
            val buf = ByteArray(MAX_MSG_SIZE)
            while (true) {
                val pkt = DatagramPacket(buf, buf.size)
                try {
                    if (channel.isClosedForSend) {
                        break
                    }
                    rcvSocket.receive(pkt)
                    val msg = packetToMessage(buf, 0, pkt.length)
                    Log.d("SOCKET", "filling channel with $msg")
                    channel.send(msg)
                } catch (ex: SocketTimeoutException) {
                } catch (ex: CancellationException) {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I think I misunderstood what `withContext` does compared to `launch`. I also didn't know it was that easy to create a `CoroutineScope` from scratch. For my understanding, what does bring this new scope compared to e.g. `viewModelScope`?

Comment: You can use built-in `viewModelScope` from `ViewModel` without creating a new `CoroutineScope`. If you can't use built-in scopes, you have to create your own to launch a coroutine.